# I installed react-native, but cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

From my command line, I ran

`npm install react-native`

In my package.json:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-modal": "^3.11.2",
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1"
```

In my package-lock.json there are plenty of entries for react-native.

But when I try to do

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
...
return <View>foo</View>
```

And run

`npm run-script build`

I get

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/components/main.component.js
Cannot find module: 'react-native'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install react-native.
```

The only hint is when I do npm install I get

`npm WARN react-native@0.62.2 requires a peer of react@16.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

but when I changed react to 16.11.0, and react-dom, it just went back to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the CLI globally, also i recommend on the community cli [@react-native-community/cli](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli) which is actually maintained.

Run `npm install -g @react-native-community/cli`,
then `npx react-native init AppName` with the globally installed cli. Don't forget to delete the obsolete cli package.